# Save copy of procedure in same database using a script

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

I am trying to work in a development database without stomping on the toes of someone else working in the same database, sometimes on the same tables, functions, and procedures.  We know what the affected code is.

For the tables it is easy:  I've got my 12 version and their 17 version.  Before working, I'll save their 17 data, and copy in my 12 data, all in a little script:

```
drop table [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps17];
select * into [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps17] from [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps];
truncate table [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps];
insert into [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps] select * from [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps12];
```

When I'm done for the day, I copy their data back:

```
drop table [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps12];
select * into [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps12] from [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps];
truncate table [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps];
insert into [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps] select * from [MTDetails].[dbo].[Taps17];
```

I want to do something similar with the procedures and functions.  And...I'm not sure how to copy a procedure automatically like that, if it is even possible.

I've made copies of my procedures by using Modify, and then manually adding a 12 to the name and creating it.  But there are 11 functions and procedures - more than I want to manually mess with each time I'm going to work in the database.  Can this be done in a script?

Comment: Sounds terrible... use your own dev databases and maintain your schema and seed data in version control.

Comment: @DaleK I can't disagree that it sounds terrible.  There's a huge amount of unaffected data - re-creating from backups or source control would be even more unmanageable. 
 Perhaps I could make a local database, but that would require them to give me a password to the remote server that is being upgraded (I need the old version).  Users and competing desires are sometimes something we have to work with.

Comment: Source control is your friend.

Comment: Sounds terrible..a real recipe for failure. Use source control, and have the ability to re-create a database localy.

Comment: @MitchWheat I see the consensus is that it is a terrible idea.  A local db won't work either, as the remote db I need to access is behind a firewall.  But a second dev db on the same server should work, I think.